# How to reduce the detail level output by a DTEXEC job?

Tags: ssis, batch-file

Is there someway to reduce the detail level that is output when running a `DTEXEC` job ?

e.g. in the cmd window I've got loads of ...

```
Progress: 2012-05-10 12:24:20.70
   Source: Import Email_to
   Post Execute: 9% complete
End Progress
Progress: 2012-05-10 12:24:20.70
   Source: Import Email_to
   Post Execute: 18% complete
End Progress
Progress: 2012-05-10 12:24:20.70
   Source: Import Email_to
   Post Execute: 27% complete
End Progress
Progress: 2012-05-10 12:24:20.71
   Source: Import Email_to
   Post Execute: 36% complete
End Progress
Progress: 2012-05-10 12:24:20.71
   Source: Import Email_to
   Post Execute: 45% complete
End Progress
.... etc ...
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the flag `/Reporting` with level `N` *(**N** stands for No reporting.)* to prevent any status being reported to the command line console.

There are other levels like **E** for only *Errors*, **W** for only *Warning*. You can pick the choice of output that you would like to see on the console.

[**Refer MSDN to know more about dtexec Utility.**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

#### Syntax usage:

```
dtexec /f Package.dtsx /Reporting N
```

#### Alternative usage:

```
dtexec /f Package.dtsx /Rep N
```

#### Example:

- Created a simple package with one empty data flow task.
- Following screenshot shows when the package was executed using dtexec utility in the command line **`without`** the flag `/Reporting`. You can notice the status of data flow task is being displayed.

[image: without flag]

- Following screenshot shows when the package was executed using dtexec utility in the command line **`with`** the flag `/Reporting`. You can notice the status of data flow task is not being displayed.

[image: with flag]

Answer (score 1):

What I manage to do so far, to eliminate some lines produced at the stdout was:

```
DTExec.exe | findstr /v /c:"Microsoft (R)" | findstr /v /c:"Copyright (C)" | findstr /v /c:"Version 10"
```

and the output looks like that:

```
Started:  1:40:22 PM
Error: 2018-09-05 13:40:22.78
...
End Error
Warning: 2018-09-05 13:40:22.79
...
End Warning
DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).
Started:  1:40:22 PM
Finished: 1:40:22 PM
Elapsed:  0.265 seconds
```

I wish to have the **awk** tool on every Windows. I will try to do something more with what we have on our Windows nodes: **cscript.exe** and some JavaScript, as I'm usually do with **awk** and **sed**.

Answer (score -1):

I see no way to suppress not wanted part of the output from DTExec.exe with /ConsoleLog and /Reporting options - the only wanted parts from the stdout below are "Error:" and "Warning" blocks. Why?!?
I will have to create a tool which will be put in the pipeline after DTExec.exe and will behave like "grep -v", to filter out all the noises which should be added to the log files. The only problem is that this is a poor Windows Server, which doesn't have powerful, standard and easy to use GNU tools like "grep", and I will have to use something ugly, what every Windows Server has by default already installed (scrtipt.exe maybe).

```
Microsoft (R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility
Version 10.50.2500.0 for 32-bit
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation 2010. All rights reserved.

Started:  1:40:22 PM
Error: 2018-09-05 13:40:22.78
...
End Error
Warning: 2018-09-05 13:40:22.79
...
End Warning
DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).
Started:  1:40:22 PM
Finished: 1:40:22 PM
Elapsed:  0.265 seconds
```